# Joining on a cancelled fiber

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, fibers

I expected that `cancel`ing `Fiber` makes it `join`able. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
object TestFiber extends App {
  implicit val contextShift: ContextShift[IO] =
    IO.contextShift(ExecutionContext.global)
  implicit val timer: Timer[IO] = IO.timer(ExecutionContext.global)

  val test = for {
    fiber <- IO.never.attempt.start
    _ <- fiber.cancel
    _ <- fiber.join
    _ <- IO(println("Finished"))
  } yield ()

  test.unsafeRunSync() //blocks instead of printing "Finished" and exit
}
```

I expected that after `cancel`, `join` would immediately return and `Finished` would be printed.

But the actual behavior is that the program hangs up. How to make a `Fiber` finished so it can be `join`able?

Comment: A **Fiber** can be either `cancelled` or `joined`. I believe calling both results in an undefined behaviour.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Is there any way to verify that a cancelled Fiber is actually cancelled (for testing purpose)

Comment: Being honest, no idea. I am actually pretty noob with **Fibers**, I would recommend you to ask in the [gotter channel](https://gitter.im/typelevel/cats-effect)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez As it turned out from the Gitter discussion the issue will be fixed in ce3. https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/issues/634

Comment: @texasbruce The issue already there :)

Comment: Why the -1 ? as a matter of fact I just stumbled upon this, like 100% exactly the same case ...

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be the intended, documented behaviour of cats-effect. The ZIO equivalent to cancel is interrupt, and it returns an Exit type that will allow you to handle all possible cases (success, error, interruption) very easily, so if possible, I'd encourage you to just switch to ZIO.

But if you need to use cats-effect, the best that I could come up with (and it's not very good) is to use a Deferred:

```scala
    def catchCancel[F[_]: Concurrent, A](io: F[A]): F[(F[Unit], F[Either[Option[Throwable], A]])] =
      for {
        deferred <- Deferred[F, Either[Option[Throwable], A]]
        fiber <- (for {
          a <- Concurrent[F].unit.bracketCase(_ => io) {
            case (_, ExitCase.Completed) => Concurrent[F].unit
            case (_, ExitCase.Error(e)) => deferred.complete(Left(Some(e))).as(())
            case (_, ExitCase.Canceled) => deferred.complete(Left(None))
          }
          _ <- deferred.complete(Right(a))
        } yield ()).start
      } yield (fiber.cancel, deferred.get)
```

And you can use it like so:

```scala
    val test = for {
      x <- catchCancel[IO, Nothing](IO.never)
      (cancel, getResult) = x
      _ <- cancel
      result <- getResult
      _ <- IO(println(s"Finished $result"))
    } yield ()
```

But seriously, why would you inflict this onto yourself? Just switch to ZIO, it fixes this problem and a boatload of others.

Comment: The question didn't mention **ZIO**, so if you are going to leave its alternative as a bonus great, but keep all your recommendations and opinions outside.

Comment: The idea on Stackoverflow is to provide the best solution to any given problem. And often enough, the best way to solve a problem is to switch to a different technology, so I will not refrain from such recommendations.

Comment: Again, you are free to suggest a _"better"_ technology. But your opinions about that are against the rules of SO. This is not a place for sharing opinions. So, just leave them out or rephrase them.